# Dividing strings

Tags: c++, directx-11

So I am writing my own code to load a obj file.
But I am trying to divide a string in this format: ( 2 Examples )

f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9

f 13/45/76 445/7776/5566 677/7/45

3 groups of 3 numbers with spaces after every place except inbetween the slashes. As of right now I have this code.

At this point in the program it has already pulled the 'f' off but there is a space before the string so its like " 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9"

The second group ( "g2" ) is the only one that does not work. it is returning, "1/2/3 7/8"

buffer is the string I'm dividing.

```
// Divide into groups
                // Create groups of 1/1/1, 2/2/1, 3/3/1 Ex
                // At this point the buffer = SPACEHEREx/y/z u/v/w xn/yn/zn
                string g1 = buffer.substr(1, buffer.find(' ', 1) - 1); // Pos 1 - First space
                string g2 = buffer.substr(buffer.find(' ', 1) + 1, buffer.find(' ', buffer.find(' ', 1) + 1) - 1); // First space - Second space
                string g3 = buffer.substr(buffer.find(' ', buffer.find(' ', 1) + 1) + 1, buffer.size()); // Second space - End
```

Comment: **Look into the `.obj` specs.** The `f` line is not guaranteed to have that exact format. So split by spaces and then split by '/'. [See here](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful to you:

http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut08.html

It describes how to load and render an .obj file.

Here is a snippet of how to read the lines from the obj file (including the faces ("f") you try to read):

```
// Initialize the indexes.
    vertexIndex = 0;
    texcoordIndex = 0;
    normalIndex = 0;
    faceIndex = 0;

    // Open the file.
    fin.open(filename);

    // Check if it was successful in opening the file.
    if(fin.fail() == true)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Read in the vertices, texture coordinates, and normals into the data structures.
    // Important: Also convert to left hand coordinate system since Maya uses right hand coordinate system.
    fin.get(input);
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        if(input == 'v')
        {
            fin.get(input);

            // Read in the vertices.
            if(input == ' ') 
            { 
                fin >> vertices[vertexIndex].x >> vertices[vertexIndex].y >> vertices[vertexIndex].z;

                // Invert the Z vertex to change to left hand system.
                vertices[vertexIndex].z = vertices[vertexIndex].z * -1.0f;
                vertexIndex++; 
            }

            // Read in the texture uv coordinates.
            if(input == 't') 
            { 
                fin >> texcoords[texcoordIndex].x >> texcoords[texcoordIndex].y;

                // Invert the V texture coordinates to left hand system.
                texcoords[texcoordIndex].y = 1.0f - texcoords[texcoordIndex].y;
                texcoordIndex++; 
            }

            // Read in the normals.
            if(input == 'n') 
            { 
                fin >> normals[normalIndex].x >> normals[normalIndex].y >> normals[normalIndex].z;

                // Invert the Z normal to change to left hand system.
                normals[normalIndex].z = normals[normalIndex].z * -1.0f;
                normalIndex++; 
            }
        }

        // Read in the faces.
        if(input == 'f') 
        {
            fin.get(input);
            if(input == ' ')
            {
                // Read the face data in backwards to convert it to a left hand system from right hand system.
                fin >> faces[faceIndex].vIndex3 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].tIndex3 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].nIndex3
                    >> faces[faceIndex].vIndex2 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].tIndex2 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].nIndex2
                    >> faces[faceIndex].vIndex1 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].tIndex1 >> input2 >> faces[faceIndex].nIndex1;
                faceIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Read in the remainder of the line.
        while(input != '\n')
        {
            fin.get(input);
        }

        // Start reading the beginning of the next line.
        fin.get(input);
    }

    // Close the file.
    fin.close();
```

**EDIT:** To address the question in the comments here is a possible solution:

```
    std::string buffer = " 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9";
    string g1 = buffer.substr(1, buffer.find(' ', 1) - 1); // Pos 1 - First space
    string g2 = buffer.substr(buffer.find(' ', 1) + 1, g1.length()); // First space - Second space
    string g3 = buffer.substr(buffer.find(' ', buffer.find(' ', 1) + 1) + 1, g1.length()); // Second space - End
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/07aVQO

The problem was the second parameter of `substr()`. It should be the length, not a position in the input string.

Comment: Please include the most important points of external resources. The external resource might go offline, burst into flames, change into an ice cream selling site or redirect to your favourite subreddit.

Comment: tried to include the part which should be answering the question.

Comment: Ok that helped and I'm doing that now. Easier and more efficient. But now out of curiosity how would I divide that string like that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputiation to comment on posts yet, my apologies.

I would definitely recommened splitting those up into different lines.
Even taking the buffer.find parts and setting them to apporpriate position names.
It would be slightly easier to debug, as well as easy to read.

And if a few extra `int`s are too much, then merge them back in once your debugging is done.

Another thing you can try is split the buffer line on spaces and just keep the "x/y/z", call a function of "split by '/'" then store those off into the appropriate variables.  I think with .obj files its "f vertex/texture/normal vertex/texture/normal ....".